# Bool Property won't update via Checkbox Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, binding

In my WPF MVVM Project (with MVVM Light) I binded the CheckBox `IsChecked` Property to a bool Property `IsTermsOfUseAccepted` from a `ValidationUserViewModel` Property in my `LoginRegisterViewModel` likes this

```
public interface IValidateUserViewModel
{
    // Other Properties..

    bool IsTermsOfUseAccepted { get; set; }

    bool IsRegistrationValid { get; }
}

public class ValidateUserViewModel : ViewModelBase, IDataErrorInfo, IValidateUserViewModel
{
    public bool IsTermsOfUseAccepted
    {
        get { return _isTermsOfUseAccepted; }
        set { Set(ref _isTermsOfUseAccepted, value); }
    }

    public bool IsRegistrationValid
        // IDataErrorInfo Stuff
        => ValidatePropertiesRegistration.All(property => GetValidationError(property) == null) 
           && IsTermsOfUseAccepted;
}

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

public class LoginRegisterViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public LoginRegisterViewModel(
        IValidateUserViewModel validateUserViewModel,
        IUserRepository userRepository)
    {
        _userRepository = userRepository;

        ValidateUserViewModel = validateUserViewModel;

        RegisterCommand = new RelayCommand(RegisterExecute, RegisterCanExecute);
    }

    public IValidateUserViewModel ValidateUserViewModel
    {
        get { return _validateUserViewModel; }
        set { Set(ref _validateUserViewModel, value); }
    }

    // RegisterCommand Stuff

    public bool RegisterCanExecute() => ValidateUserViewModel.IsRegistrationValid;
}
```

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="Messenger4u.View.LoginRegisterView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:control="clr-namespace:Messenger4u.View.Control"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:metro="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
         DataContext="{Binding LoginRegister,
                               Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
         d:DesignHeight="300"
         d:DesignWidth="300"
         mc:Ignorable="d">

    <!-- Stuff -->

    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ValidateUserViewModel.IsTermsOfUseAccepted}" />

    <!-- Stuff -->

</UserControl>
```

But my problem is, that all Properties binded to TextBoxes etc. just working finde except the `IsTermsOfUseAccept` Property.
I already tried to set manually `RaisePropertyChanged`, putting the bool in the `LoginRegisterViewModel` directly, setting in XAML `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` and `Mode=TwoWay`, but nothing worked.

What could be the problem?

Comment: @Sakura Thanks, that worked.. but why it has to be a Nullable bool? And now the CheckBox ist filled with a minus `-` by default and needs to be clicked twice to be true.. can I change that?

Comment: Because CheckBox have 3 state: Check, Uncheck, and Not Determine.

Comment: You have to set default value for `_isTermsOfUseAccepted`. See my answer.

Comment: Tools like Snoop are useful for examining bindings and data contexts at runtime.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change IsChecked binding to TwoWay and set UpdateSourceTrigger to be explicit:

```
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding ValidateUserViewModel.IsTermsOfUseAccepted, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}" />
```

And change this:

```
public bool IsTermsOfUseAccepted
```

To:

```
bool? _isTermsOfUseAccepted = false; // or true, if you like
public bool? IsTermsOfUseAccepted
```

add the `?` mark

Comment: Thanks! Works fine, except when I set `UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit`, it won't update too.

Comment: Then use your old bind. Each case have different bind. Anyway, glad the code help you.

Comment: Explicit bindings have to be triggered manually, and are almost never useful unless doing low level work.